# Windows 10 Image (WIM) validation

Tags: windows, images, hashing, imaging, verification

Years ago one could use ghost to image a drive and then hash the result.  When the image was restored, the new drive could also be hashed to validate the integrity of the image.  Is there any similar validation function in modern windows 10 imaging?  My use case is as follows.  I have a gold windows 10 image that I want to have a third party supplier apply to any machine they sell me.  I want to hash or otherwise create an integrity check on the image prior to releasing it to the vendor.  When the vendor delivers a batch of machines I want to be able to hash (or whatever method is appropriate) the drive of an imaged machine to validate the image I provided is the exact image that's on the system.  Does such technology still exist?

Comment: I believe this can be done with gimagex. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-tools/gimagex/ however you should do some research about it, if this is what you are looking for

Comment: You can create a MD5 hash on any file including a WIM.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool from Microsoft called DSIM. 
You can check the integrity from a cosole  CMD doing:

```
DISM.exe /Append-Image /ImageFile:<path_to_image_file> /Name:<image_name> /CheckIntegrity
```

And also:

```
DISM.exe /Append-Image /ImageFile:<path_to_image_file> /Name:<image_name> /Verify
```

More info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14

Comment: `/Append-Image` does not work like this, it would need a capture directory to append to the image. `/CheckIntegrity` can only be used when capturing, modifying, or applying the image, not in a stand-alone manner.